# C# Win8.1 Universal App Background Task: Using CancelOnConditionLoss crashes app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm building an universal app with a background task. When registering the task I'm applying a system condtion with cancel on condition loss set to true:

```
builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserNotPresent));
builder.CancelOnConditionLoss = true;
```

This works, but the issue is that when the condition loss is trigger that app crashes. If I don't use cancel on conditioin loss the task continues to run even though the "user is present". Any help or advice with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the background task run method:

```
async public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(taskInstance.Task.Name + " task is running.......");

    //Get a deferral if we're doing async work.
    BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    try
    {
        taskInstance.Canceled += (s, e) =>
        {
            cancelRequest = true;
            s.Task.Unregister(true);
            Debug.WriteLine(s.Task.Name + " task has been cancelled.");
        };

        while (cancelRequest == false)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("inside loop");

            await Task.Delay(15000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("An Error Has Occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

UPDATE:
With further investigation, noticed that in output console that the app is throwing this error: WWAHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1)

Comment: Where is deferral.Complete() ?

Comment: It's after the try/catch, just a copy and pastes mistake :)